# How to check for Route through route name in template with Meteor and Iron Router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

What can I use in a template to figure out the `route name` that is associated with the route that I am currently on?

For example if I configured a route like so in `iron-router`

```
this.route('quick', {
    path: '/wow/:_id',
    template: 'create_question'
});
```

So if I am on the route `/wow/123` how can I get the router's name in my template, in this case how can I get `quick` in my template?

I'm simply looking for a function, I am sure I can use a handlebars helper to get the rest done. I just need a function to call.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### iron-router > 1.0

```
var routeName = Router.current().route.getName();
```

### iron-router < 1.0

```
var routeName = Router.current().route.name;
```

Answer (score 16):

For the newer iron router, use:

```
var routeName = Router.current().route.getName()
```

This will output the name of the actual route you defined with `this.route()`

Answer (score 4):

You can define any options you want in your route config :

```
Router.route('/', {
    name : 'home',
    template : 'home',
    title: 'Home'
});
```

and then access to title with this :

```
Router.current().route.options.title
```

This will output "Home"

Answer (score 0):

You can try Router.current().template