# How can I change behavior of Meteor template events on an included template?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

I have a template that shows a table of posts. The user can edit, add, and delete posts. My site has two different varieties of posts: it has a shared library of posts and each user has posts attached to their profile.

[image: Articles table]

My table is the same across the site, but the CRUD operations are different based on whether it's displaying the user's posts or the site's shared post library. For example, when a user adds a post, I need to run `Meteor.users.update({_id: [user ID]}, {$push: {'profile.posts': postObject}})`. When the site admin adds a post, I need to run `Articles.insert(postObject)`.

What is the best way to do this? I tried passing an argument to my template inclusion (i.e. `{{> postsTable source=Articles}}`) and testing for that in the event functions, but it seems this *replaces* the data context which means my template can no longer get to the posts. I also thought about testing the current route and using that to branch the event functions, but that method seems a bit smelly.

Alternatively, I could bind events for the templates that include the table rather than on the table template itself. This is probably the simplest solution, but I would be duplicating a lot of code across those various templates when the only thing that changes is how the resulting data is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that using the [current route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213122/how-to-check-for-route-through-route-name-in-template-with-meteor-and-iron-route) is an unfortunate mixing of concerns. I'll admit we do that in our app in a few places to get around this exact issue.

If possible, I'd recommend modifying the context to the included `postTable` template. You have a couple of options:

**rename the context and add more variables**

```
{{> postsTable data=this isArticles=true}}
```

Now your `postsTable` has access to both the parent context and the `isArticles` boolean. The only trick is that you'll need to access the context via the `data` namespace (or whatever you choose to call it) which may seem a little verbose.

**extend the context in a helper**

Add a helper to the parent template which extends its context like this:

```js
Template.parentTemplate.helpers({
  context: function() {
    var result = _.clone(this);
    result.isArticles = false;
    return result;
  }
});
```

Then in your template you can do:

```
{{> postsTable context}}
```

Your `postsTable` template will then have the parent context along with the `isArticles` boolean. This is the technique we prefer whenever possible.

Also see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015971/pass-parameters-to-template-without-overriding-data-context) if you'd prefer to do this with a global helper.